confusion on understanding how calderon zygmund decomposition
I am not able to see how by Calderon zygmund decomposition. We have
$|\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: M_{D}g(x) > \lambda \}| \leq \frac{1}{\lambda} \int_{\{M_{D}g(x) > \lambda\}}|g(x)|dx$.
Here $M_{D}$ is dyadic maximal operator.
